# Como testear i18n en Next.js 13, verificando cambio de locale o de url

Tags: typescript, next.js, jest

Estoy intentando testear el cambio de lenguaje,he intentado probar click en el botón del lenguaje comprobar que la url cambie, pero no logro que haga el llamado.

**Componente:**

*LangButtons.tsx*

```javascript
import useTranslations from '@/hooks/useTranslations'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const LangButtons = () => {
  const { asPath } = useRouter()
  const { currentLang, langs } = useTranslations()

  return (
    <nav>
      {langs!.map(
        (lang) =>
          currentLang !== lang && (
            <Link key={lang} locale={lang} href={asPath}>
              <div role="button">{lang.split('-')[0]}</div>
            </Link>
          ),
      )}
    </nav>
  )
}

export default LangButtons
```

**Test:**

*LangButtons.test.tsx*

```javascript
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import LangButtons from '.'

const mockRouter = jest.fn()

jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('next/router'),
  useRouter: () => mockRouter(),
}))

jest.mock('@/hooks/useTranslations', () => () => ({
  currentLang: 'es-AR',
  langs: ['en-US', 'es-AR', 'pt-BR'],
}))

describe('LangButtons', () => {
  it('should change path on button click', () => {
    const onMock = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true))
    const emitMock = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true))
    const pushMock = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true))

    mockRouter.mockImplementation(() => ({
      push: pushMock,
      prefetch: () => Promise.resolve(true),
      asPath: 'pt-BR',
      events: {
        off: jest.fn(),
        emit: emitMock,
        on: onMock,
      },
    }))

    render(<LangButtons />)

    const portugueseButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /pt/i })
    fireEvent.click(portugueseButton)

    expect(pushMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(emitMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(onMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

**Hook que utilizo en el componente LangButtons.tsx**

*useTranslations.ts*

```javascript
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import languages, { TranslationFile } from '@/locales/resources'

const useTranslations = () => {
  const { locale, locales } = useRouter()
  const translations = languages[locale!] as TranslationFile

  return { translations, currentLang: locale, langs: locales }
}

export default useTranslations
```

**resources.ts**

```javascript
import EN from './translation-en.json'
import ES from './translation-es.json'
import PT from './translation-pt.json'

export type TranslationFile = typeof import('./translation-en.json')

interface Languages {
  [keyof: string]: TranslationFile
}

const languages: Languages = {
  'en-US': EN,
  'es-AR': ES,
  'pt-BR': PT,
}

export default languages
```

He hecho varios intentos, como tratar de obtener la ruta modificada a través del objeto window.location, probando propiedades cómo `href`, `pathname`, entre otras. Como se muestra en el código actual. También intenté escuchar llamadas a los métodos dentro del objeto `useRouter` sin éxito, y dentro de diferentes maneras de mockear el `useRouter`, la utilizada en el snippet que paso fue la única que realmente lo logró. Me basé para ello en este artículo, lo recomiendo.
[Jest Mock](https://www.bam.tech/en/article/fix-jest-mock-cannot-access-before-initialization-error)